# Google chrome looks different as root

Tags: debian, chrome

Why google chrome looks different when I run it (On Debian 10) as root? 
Text fonts seem to be thinner.

Chrome without root the text appears in bold
[image]

Chorme as root the text is not bold
[image]

Is it possible to make it look the same?
Thanks in advance

Comment: somebody else will be more qualified to discuss where font settings lie, but … why are you running Chrome as root to begin with?

Comment: I am launching chrome from docker to be able to access various applications using DNS that run within a docker network. The docker image I have runs chrome as root.